# Require review of group A's pull requests by group B in TFS git?

Tags: git, tfs

In a git repository set up on TFS 2015, is it possible to set up a branch policy such that users in group A must have their pull requests reviewed by members of group B? For example, JuniorDevelopers can't approve other JuniorDevelopers; they must receive approval from SeniorDevelopers.

The policy settings in the administration pages seem pretty rudimentary and only seem to be able to set up minimum numbers of reviewers or that specific code items must be reviewed by specific people or groups.

A basic thing like Junior vs. Senior I assume would be possible in a roundabout way through something like setting that all code in the root directory must be reviewed by someone in the SeniorDevelopers group. But what about a more advanced configuration such as "group A can only be approved by group B, but group B can only be approved by group A"?

Comment: The juniors need to be reviewed by seniors is possible. But A by B and B by A isn't AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in the same branch we can only set the effective policy to **One-way** review. A by B and B by A  to some extent, it means that no policy is set, it can not restrict eachother.

As a workaround you can create two branches, one for JuniorDevelopers (A by B) and antoher for SeniorDevelopers (B by A). Thus you can set the branch policy separately. Then merge branches once feature complated as needed.

[image]

Comment: OK. The thought of using branches for this did occur to me after asking the question but adds a bit of extra complexity that I'd probably rather avoid unless it's needed.